# Iterative Implementation of Negamax Alpha-Beta

Tags: c#

Please help me check the correctness of this c# iterative implementation of [negamax](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Negamax)! Thank you! Your help highly appreciated! Also, please help me out how to add [alpha beta pruning](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Alpha-Beta) to this(it was supposed to be alpha beta with negamax, but i forgot the alpha beta part... :<)! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I DO think that the implementaqtion works. I only want it to be checked. Also, i simply want SUGGESTIONS and GUIDANCE on how to add alpha beta to the algorithm, not someone write the code for me. Please do not be mistaken. Thank you.

```
Random r = new Random();

Stack<int> maxs = new Stack<int>();

Stack<int> levels = new Stack<int>();
Stack<string> todo = new Stack<string>();

Stack<string> undo = new Stack<string>();

maxs.Push(int.MinValue);

var le = legals(bd);
while (le.Any())
{
    var mv = le[r.Next(le.Count)];
    le.Remove(mv);
    todo.Push(mv);
    levels.Push(1);
}

while (todo.Any())
{
    //init
    string mv = todo.Pop();
    int level = levels.Pop();
    undo.Push(mv);
    if (level != depthleft) maxs.Push(int.MinValue);
    move(mv, level % 2 == 0 ? "b" : "w");

    //expand children/do operations,cleanup
    if (level == depthleft)
    {
         int score = -eval(bd, level % 2 == 0);
         if (score > maxs.Last())
         {
              maxs.Pop();
              maxs.Push(score);
         }
         unmove(undo.Pop());

         int diff = level - levels.Last();
         if (diff != 0)
         {
              for (; diff > 0; diff--)
              {
                   score = -maxs.Pop();
                   if (score > maxs.Last())
                   {
                        maxs.Pop();
                        maxs.Push(score);
                   }
                   unmove(undo.Pop());
              }
         }
     }
     else
     {
          var ls = legals(bd);
          while (ls.Any())
          {
              var child = ls[r.Next(ls.Count)];
              ls.Remove(child);
              todo.Push(child);
              levels.Push(level + 1);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I think your question does not fit well on this site. This site is for requests to improve code that you think works, not to check whether it works at all and certainly not to write code for you.

Comment: yes, i think my code should work. i just want someone to check its correctness on behalf of puny me. also, i only wanted SUGGESTIONS on howto incooperate alpha beta into the algorithm, certainly not necessarily writing code for me either. maybe it was my unclear question. ill edit it

Comment: @idiotretard (such an odd name): your question seems to fit on StackOverflow. HTH

Comment: ... i initially posted this on stack overflow, got told to move it here, and got closed there... wth should i do then!?

Comment: "What kind of questions can I ask here?

Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…

Best practices and design pattern usage
Security issues
Performance
Correctness in unanticipated cases
then you are in the right place!"

Comment: "I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?
Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer must be yes to all questions:

Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
Did I write that code?
Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
If you answered yes to all the above questions, your question is on-topic for Code Review."

Comment: i can tell you i DO believe that my question was on topic AND i would definitely answer yes to all the five questions

Comment: This question is on-topic, as the current community consensus sees it.

Comment: `... i initially posted this on stack overflow, got told to move it here, and got closed there... wth should i do then!?` Oh man, sorry that we trapped you in a vicious bureaucratic circle - it was definitely not intentional. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick suggestions:

- Split the code into smaller methods, with understandable names - it will become simpler!
- Use clear variable names (even if they are longer) and try to avoid "shortenings";
- **Never** use less than 3 characters for variable names... `le`? `r`? `mv`?!? (`int i` in for cycles is an exception because it is idiomatic);
- Use PascalCase (not camelCase) for methods and properties;
- Use camelCase (not lowercase) for local variables;
- Don't repeat code (`var le = legals(bd); while (le.Any()) { ... }`), extract it to a method.